# Remove Facebook photos from Windows 8 Photo Gallery

Tags: windows-8, windows-photo-gallery

I have disconnected Facebook from Windows 8, but the pictures are still showing in Photo Gallery. How do I remove the photos? I do not just want to hide the tile, but would like the pictures removed completely.

Comment: what u tried?did u downloaded the photos/viewed online?have u tried clearing temp memory?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out just now. You need to log into your microsoft account online. From there, hit "Manage Accounts." You should see facebook on there. Click it and remove the button that says share photos with windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You simply open the photos app, select the photos that you no longer want on your computer, and then choose the option to delete them. You will have to delete each photo explicitly. You can, fortunately, select multiple photos at once and then delete them as a group.

Comment: The pics are not in the photo app...they are on a tile that pops up when I hit photo app call facebook. there are other tiles there with flikr and skydrive but the fb on still has all my fb photos on it. I have stopped the sync with fb and my computer and even deleted the photo app and reinstalled it but the darn pics are still there

Answer (score -1):

log in to microsoft account.. at the right upper corner .. put the arrow to your picture.. then hit view profile. then you will see a small facebook logo then hit it.. then click uncheck the box on the lower part of the choices ("view your facebook photos and videos").. thats it,, go back to photo gallery.. :D :)

Comment: How does this add to the answer given on December 7, 2013?